# Profit maximization in a monopoly

Tags: microeconomics, monopoly

> Suppose two goods $1$ and $2$ are produced by a monopolist firm. The market demands are $$q_1(p_1, p_2) = a-p_1+bp_2 \tag{1}$$
> $$q_2(p_1, p_2) = a-p_2+bp_1 \tag{2}$$
>
> and the cost functions are $c_i(q_i) = cq_i$.
>
> What's the profit maximizing price of the monopolist?

The profit function is given by $\pi(p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2) = (p_1-c)q_1 + (p_2-c)q_2$. We need to solve the following maximization problem: $$\max[\pi(p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2)] \text{ subject to } q_1 = a-p_1+bp_2 \text{ and } q_2 = a-p_2+bp_1$$

The Lagrangian is $\mathcal{L}(p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2) = \pi + \lambda_1(\cdot) + \lambda_2(\cdot)$ which upon solving $\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial p_i} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q_i} = 0\right)$ gives us nothing more than plugging in equations (1) and (2). Where am I going wrong?

---

I am not looking for ways to solve this: I am aware that differentiating $\pi$ wrt $p_1$ and $p_2$ will give the answer. I am curious why the constrained maximization set-up isn't working here.

Comment: what do you mean it does not work? It seems that it is working. Constrained optimization problem is not in principle different from substitution method. It is just a more convenient way to solve optimization problems where direct substitution is too difficult, you should generally get the same solution whether you substitute or use lagrangian, similarly as calculus yields the same top of parabola as solving for vertex of parabola algebraically

Comment: @1muflon1 You're right. Yes, it finds the local optimum values while ensuring the "conditions" (which is essentially substitution). I computed it incorrectly and so I didn't get anything beyond vague values of $\lambda$ and the two conditions. Thank you for confirming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was based on a miscalculation.